# What does "zoning" mean for fighting games?

Tags: terminology

I've seen the terms "zone" and "anti-zone" used in regards to moves, as well as discussion about whether or not a character is a good "zoner" or has a good "zoning game."

What exactly does this term mean? Is it movement speed, avoidance ability, a combination of the two or something else?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

> Zoning: Intentionally keeping
>   distance/pressure on your opponent,
>   either reading their style or forcing
>   them into playing a certain way.
>   Adaptive to close combat situations
>   and able to make good on big damage
>   opportunities. (sic)
>   [...]
>   A good zoning player will always
>   create opportunities for themselves by
>   keeping their opponent away from them
>   as to gain control of the match, then
>   adjust to their opponent's
>   tactics/counters and act accordingly.
>   (sic)
>   [...]
>   Zoning doesn't *have* to involve
>   repeated moves at all. Zoning isn't
>   just keeping your distance, it's about
>   keeping within a very specific
>   distance, which may not even be a half
>   screen away. It might be just barely
>   within range of a normal move. The
>   idea is to establish this distance and
>   keep it, because it limits your
>   opponent's options and allows you to
>   react more easily, giving *you* the
>   control of the match.

Source: http://www.trmk.org/forums/showthread.php/22827-The-Difference-Between-Zoning-and-Spamming

Comment: This is a cool answer!

Comment: Could you not also consider it as a kind of control of your opponents "safe zone"by zoning the area into sections that are safe, risky, and dangerous for them due to your actions. You can after all gain control specifically by getting up close and personal if you are stronger than them at close range. You are basically controlling where they can be and what they can do without risking heavy losses just to keep up.